# bug while submitting the form data

Tags: reactjs, rest, antd

I have created a form using `antd` and wanted to submit the data to my database  and  I have created the below function

```
 handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
        this.setState({
          data:values
        })
        console.log('this is i ', this.state.data);
      }
    });
  }
```

When I submit the data from the form data is stored in variable called `values` . When I submit the form first time. It displays the following in console
[as shown in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Nm9A.png). When I clicked once again submit the data is passed  to the second console [as shown image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBgHp.png). Can I know where I went wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't done anything wrong. That's actually the expected behavior when you try to `console.log(this.state)` right after calling `this.setState({})` This logic happens almost simultaneously so you wouldn't be able to print your new state-data right away.

If you want to execute an action using your new state-data, you can utilize the optional, second argument inside `this.setState({})` which is actually a call-back. It has access to your new state-data. See below:

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
        this.setState({
          data:values
        }, () => console.log(this.state.data))
      }
    });
  }
```